Powershell Sort-Object by all columns without referencing the column names (dynamically)
I have a process that compares two sets files to another set of files.  The file names between the two sets are the same.  However, there are files in each set with different numbers of columns.  But I want to use Powershell to sort all the files regardless of the number or name of the columns.
So how do I use the Powershell Sort-Object to sort by all columns and not reference the column names?  I started with the following but it's not actually sorting the columns.
# Create a hashtable to store column indices
$columnIndices = @{}

# Populate the hashtable with column names and their indices
foreach ($column in $dataTable.Columns) {
    $columnIndices[$column.ColumnName] = $column.Ordinal
}

$sortedDataTable = $dataTable | Sort-Object -Property { $sortedcolumnIndices[$_.ColumnName] }
$sortedDataTable | Export-Csv -Path $csvFileNameAndPath -NoTypeInformation


$dataTable and $sortedcolumnIndices are undefined variables.. Next, what do you mean by sort by all columns ? What kind of sorting is that?

You need an array of numbers from the array of column names.  So try this : $columnNames = @('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(0, $columnNames.Length)
